# Xamarin IOS Change color of button momentarily

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm creating a quiz application. The user selects an answer, get a brief confirmation whether the answer is correct or wrong before automatically is directed to the next question. 
So, I have a view that has a label and 4 different buttons with different texts coming from database. When the user selects a button, it should flash or have a different background color for few seconds before the buttons are loaded with different text.

I have tried doing this in the touchUpInside. I set a different color for the button and I do Thread.Sleep(2000). This is my event handler of the TouchUpInside of one of the buttons:

```
    partial void Answer(MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)
    {
        // if wrong answer, highlight to red and move on.
        ((UIButton)sender).backgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        Sleep(2000); // freeze to display the red color for 2 seconds
        LoadNextQuestion(); // load the next question method
    }
```

But the color only changes after the next question loads. How can I make it freeze there for 2 seconds?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an animation:

```
button1.TouchDown += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  UIView.Animate(2,0,UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse,
    () => { button2.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow; }, 
    () => { button2.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green; });
};
```

Here button1 is triggering the animation of button2, but you could setup the trigger to be anything.  This sample just animates the button's background color from Green to Yellow and back Again, with a 2s duration.